# Show Hide Header based on their respective home page with vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

By default I have header-one which can be seen in all the pages. Then there comes header-two and header-three which are only shown when there respective home pages are been opened . Is there anyway we can do by condition if the path is '/home-one' not '/home-two' and '/home-three' then show header-v1

```html
//App.vue//
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
 <v-app>
  <header-v1></header-v1>
    <header-v2></header-v2>
    <header-v3></header-v3>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <emb-footer-V1></emb-footer-V1>
 </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

Several ways you could approach this using props, a route watcher, meta, etc.

Here's an example using meta on each route:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: {
      template: '<div>home page</div>'
    }
  }, {
    path: '/home-one',
    component: {
      template: '<div>home page one</div>'
    },
    meta: {
      header: 1
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/home-two',
    component: {
      template: '<div>home page two</div>'
    },
    meta: {
      header: 2
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/home-three',
    component: {
      template: '<div>home page three</div>'
    },
    meta: {
      header: 3
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1 v-if="$route.meta.header === 1">I'm visible on home page one</h1>
  <h2 v-else-if="$route.meta.header === 2">I'm visible on home page two</h2>
  <h3 v-else-if="$route.meta.header === 3">I'm visible on home page three</h3>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/home-one">Home One</router-link>
    <router-link to="/home-two">Home Two</router-link>
    <router-link to="/home-three">Home Three</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: can we make the header one disappear if we click on home Two and home three ?

Comment: can we add condition to header one as header one visible for all screen but when clicked on home two and home three there individual header shows

Comment: Can we  dissapear all the three headers when scroll downwards and show the fixed header  @DigitalDrifter???

Comment: @Aishwerya Sure, however that is probably better suited for a new question. You had originally asked about conditionally showing page elements depending on the current route, so if you want to post another question I would be happy to help. It also helps other find answers to their specific questions.